# Ejercicios de reduccion

Tags: math-mode

```
\[ \begin{align*}
2x + 3y &= 8 \\
4x - 2y &= 6
\end{align*} \]
```

Multiplicamos la primera ecuación por 2 para igualar los coeficientes de (x):

```
\[ \begin{align*}
4x + 6y &= 16 \\
4x - 2y &= 6
\end{align*} \]
```

Restamos la segunda ecuación de la primera:

```
\[ 8y = 10 \]
```

Por lo tanto, `\(y = \frac{5}{4}\)`. Sustituimos `\(y\)` en la primera ecuación para encontrar `\(x\)`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your (incomplete) code fragment to complete small document which we ca test as it is. BTW: `align*`  is not allowed to be nested in equation (`\[ ... \]`) environment

Comment: Note that this is English speaking community, so please transfer your question into English

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your (otherwise unstated) question is: *Why do*

```
\[ \begin{align*}
2x + 3y &= 8 \\
4x - 2y &= 6
\end{align*} \]
```

*and related code chunks throw errors?*

The answer to this question is: Both `\[` and `\begin{align}` initiate display math mode, and both `\end{align*}` and `\]` terminate display math mode. It is illegal to enter display math mode if you're already in math mode; likewise, it's illegal to exit display math mode if you're not (or no longer) in math mode.

What to do? Easy: Just get rid of the `\[` and `\]` pairs.